# SAP integration patterns RFC BAPI + outbound IDOC

Tags: integration, saprfc, bapi, idoc, integration-patterns

I am trying to understand all of the SAP integration patterns (and anti-patterns in that matter).

What I am sure that are the patterns:

- sync BAPI
- async BAPI
- IDOCs (inbound + outbound; or just one direction)

When doing actual integration with SAP, I have noticed also a pattern with BAPI RFC request and an outbound IDOC as a response. Is this also a valid pattern?

I would appreciate if anyone has a documentation source of various integration patterns with SAP.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no single point for SAP integration documentation. What  is your exact task?

Comment: @Suncatcher, I am trying to understand what is the "right" way to integrate with SAP.

Comment: there is no "right" way. It depends. There are such mastodonic legacy systems where the most suitable way of integration with SAP would be sending flat files :)

Comment: :) Thanks @Suncatcher, I will work on that. It was funny that I couldn't find any patterns, so now you just confirmed why not!

Comment: what would be the best literature/resources to start with RFC SAP integration?!

Answer (score -1):

SAP integration can be a daunting task. I have been working on several SAP integration assignments. While I have summarized some of my learnings below, you can get started with [SAP integration guide](https://www.veonconsulting.com/sap-integration-best-practices/) over here which details of how to go about executing your assignment.

- Inadequate understanding of SAP's capability leads to unnecessary customization of SAP infrastructure.
- Care must be taken so that core SAP functionalities are not affected due to added integration load on the system.
- Through understanding of SAP versions, supported integration protocols and best practices is essential for designing a proper solution.
- Intense validation of nature of integration (real time / periodic) is also needed.

Wish you all the best for your assignment.